# How to handle constructor and access control system using OZ library in Diamond Implementation

Tags: solidity, blockchain, openzeppelin, proxy-contracts

solidity guys
I have started to implement Diamond in a Simple Contract, but I don't have any idea about constructor and access control.
Here is my simple contract(MyContract.sol)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract MyContract is AccessControl {

    bytes32 public constant PAUSER_ROLE = keccak256("PAUSER_ROLE");
    address public tokenAddress;

    modifier onlyAdmin() {
        require(hasRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender), "Caller is not admin");
        _;
    }

    constructor(address _admin) {
        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _admin);
        _setupRole(PAUSER_ROLE, _admin);
    }

    function setTokenAddress(address _tokenAddress)
        external
        onlyAdmin
    {
        tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
    }
}
```

And my roughly tried MyContractFacet contract is as follows

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

bytes32 constant PAUSER_ROLE = keccak256("PAUSER_ROLE");

struct AppStorage {
    address tokenAddress;
}

contract MyContractFacet is AccessControl {

    AppStorage internal s;

    modifier onlyAdmin() {
        require(hasRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender), "Caller is not admin");
        _;
    }

    constructor(address _admin) {
        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _admin);
        _setupRole(PAUSER_ROLE, _admin);
    }

    function setTokenAddress(address _tokenAddress)
        external
        onlyAdmin
    {
        s.tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
    }
}
```

I hope to learn how to handle constructor and access control of OZ library in my Diamond implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added some useful links that I have got from Discord sever. Hope this help others who have same questions with me

- Openzeppelin library currently don't use Diamond Storage, so can't use contracts from OZ. Instead of it, can use this library - [solidstate-solidity](https://github.com/solidstate-network/solidstate-solidity)
- Please read [this article](https://eip2535diamonds.substack.com/p/constructor-functions-dont-work-in) to know about constructors in facets
- Also, read [this](https://eip2535diamonds.substack.com/p/how-storage-works-in-eip2535-diamonds) to know how storage works in diamond

Updated MyContractFacet.sol is as follows

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "solidstate/contracts/access/access_control/AccessControl.sol";
import { AccessControlStorage } from "solidstate/contracts/access/access_control/AccessControlStorage.sol";

bytes32 constant PAUSER_ROLE = keccak256("PAUSER_ROLE");

struct AppStorage {
    address tokenAddress;
}

contract MyContractFacet is AccessControl {
    AppStorage internal s;

    function initialize(address _admin) external {
        _grantRole(AccessControlStorage.DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _admin);
        _grantRole(PAUSER_ROLE, _admin);
    }

    modifier onlyAdmin() {
        require(_hasRole(AccessControlStorage.DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender), "Caller is not admin");
        _;
    }

    function setTokenAddress(address _tokenAddress)
        external
        onlyAdmin
    {
        s.tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
    }

}
```